# The Input Box keeps popping up in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to type code in VBA where a macro button pops up based on a cell value and the password typed after a cell has that specific value. It works for the most part, but the Input Box keeps popping up after I have typed the password. Whenever I click on another cell or type something in a different cell, the input box keeps popping up after I've typed the password for admin. I am not sure why it does that.

```
Sub enable_()
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
'If user is selected, hide button. If admin is selected, enter password to see the button'

If Range("A5") = "User" Then ActiveSheet.CommandButton1.Visible = False
If Range("A5") = "Admin" Then
    strwork = InputBox("Please enter Admin Password.")
    If strwork = "excel" Then ActiveSheet.CommandButton1.Visible = True
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You probably need to use `Intersect` with `Target` to only proceed if specific cell(s) were changed.

Comment: Hi BigBen, I have never heard of this function. Can you provide an example?

Comment: I put it at the end of the code. It still asks for an input box.

Comment: Whoops, should be `If Intersect(Target, Me.Range("A5)) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub`, and put it at the beginning.

Comment: Yes this is working now. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

### `Worksheet Change` feat. `InputBox`

- [`Application.Intersect method`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.intersect)

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
' If user is selected, hide button.
' If admin is selected, enter password to see the button'
    
    Dim sCell As Range: Set sCell = Me.Range("A5")
    If Intersect(Target, sCell) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    With Me.CommandButton1
        Select Case sCell.Value
        Case "User"
            If .Visible Then .Visible = False
        Case "Admin"
            Dim pWord As String
            pWord = InputBox("Please enter Admin Password.")
            'If .Visible Then .Visible = False
            If pWord = "excel" Then
                If Not .Visible Then .Visible = True
            End If
        End Select
    End With
        
End Sub
```